# How can I categorize emojis in emojione library?

Tags: javascript, emoji

I am trying to display all emojis available in emojione library without doing it by hand like:

```
<img class="emojione" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.5.0/assets/png/1F601.png">
```

I have looked at the emojione.js and I see that there is a emojioneList there which contains an array of all available emojis with their codes. However there is no info on category.

On the other hand when I look at the emojione website you can clearly see that they managed to categorize them:

http://emoji.codes/family

I seriously doubt that they did this by hand or that they have a database for this. So what am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The emojione package also includes a json file 'emojiione.json' that has each emoji as an object with all its relevant information (including categories).

Comment: This is the correct answer. I figured this out in the meantime myself but that doesn't change the fact that your answer is correct...

Comment: @Marko In that case you could have posted an answer yourself before so others with the same question would have found the answer earlier ;)